# Given $\frac{\det(A+B_{j})}{\det(A)} \leq \gamma$, upper bound $\frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M}B_{j})}{\det(A)}$ in terms of $\gamma$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Assume symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is positive definite, and symmetric matrices $B_{j} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}, j=1,\dots,M$ are positive semi-definite.

It is also given that $$\frac{\det(A+B_{j})}{\det(A)} \leq \gamma$$ for $\forall j \in [M]$, where $\gamma$ is a positive constant.

The question is how to upper bound $$\frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M} B_{j})}{\det(A)}$$ in terms of $\gamma$.

A very naive way I can think of is first showing that $$\frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M} B_{j})}{\det(A)} \leq \gamma \cdot \frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} B_{j})}{\det(A)}$$, which can be done by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\gamma &\geq \frac{\det(A+B_{M})}{\det(A)} \\
& \geq \frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M} B_{j})}{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} B_{j})} \\
& = \frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M} B_{j})}{\det(A)} \cdot \frac{\det(A)}{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} B_{j})}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658659/effect-of-adding-a-matrix-to-both-numerator-and-denominator-of-a-ratio-between-d) for proof of second step).

Then we can apply this for $M$ times, and find that:
$$\frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M} B_{j})}{\det(A)} \leq \gamma^{M}$$
, but this upper bound is very loose because of the second step above.

I am wondering how I can get a tighter upper bound for $\frac{\det(A+\sum_{j=1}^{M} B_{j})}{\det(A)}$, e.g. with the help of [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) perhaps. Any suggestion is appeciated!